# Reverse of RxJS debounce time operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs

So if debounce time waits a certain amount of time until it allows another emission, I was wondering if there's an operator that waits for a certain amount of time to have elapsed before it actually emits the emissions.

So the diagram might look like this

```
--1--2--3--4--5---------------Y-------------->
              |_______________| <-- A period of time X
                      X              1-5 are emitted at time Y which is the emission time of 5+X
```

Essentially it delays the emissions and collects them, then emits them after the delay.

Hopefully this is clear enough.

Edit: After some more research I've just found `bufferTime`, it looks like this is close to what I want, but I specifically want the collected values to be emitted after a period of time after the last value.

Comment: After some more research I've just found `bufferTime`, it looks like this would work?

Comment: actually debounceTime behaves just as you have drawn, just it emmits only the 5th event after X period. Do you want to get all the 5 events after events stop for the period of X?

Comment: @Andrei The values are actually irrelevant, I just need to know when an amount of time has elapsed so I can trigger something off the back of it. So debounceTime would work then?

Comment: it seems  like it is the operator you need. the concept of the word "debounce" is exactly like it, even if we speak about something different rather than rxjs. The text in the questions (busy for X milliseconds after the first event) sounds like it is about throttleTime operator

Comment: @Andrei Unfortunately throttleTime won't work as I need all values to be ignored until the period of time X has elapsed after the first emission. Can I just ask if the debounceTime duration is continuously ticking or does the duration only begin after it receives a value from the Observable?

Comment: debounceTime(X)  emits the last event from its source when the source stops emitting for X milliseconds. so if source is clicks stream and you click like crazy for an hour, it won't emit any events, untill you stop clicking for X milliseconds, and you will get an event in stopTime + X milliseconds moment

Comment: I think you are searching this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-buffer-with-debounce

Answer (score 1):

In a sequence of emitted values, debounce time discards values received prior to the end of a duration in favor of the last emitted value. The opposite IMO would be to store the initially emitted value and discard the proceeding ones, within a duration of time for successive values.

The operator for this is **throttleTime**

In your case however, you could create a Higher order observable, that emits only after all 5 values have emitted, and delay this final emission by a duration x.

Answer (score 0):

I ended here based on the title.
My problem: I had a css grey-out of the website, if a endpoint couldn't be polled anymore (non-modern endpoint). First instinct that I need the reverse of `debounce` was wrong.

My solution with angular/rxjs.
A css class was linked to a property `fresh`.
The stream updates every update to `true`. But with lack of updates `debounceTime` is triggered, and `fresh` becomes false.

```
this.updates$
  .pipe(
    tap((x) => {
      this.fresh = true;
    }),
    debounceTime(2*1000)
  )
  .subscribe((x) => {
    this.fresh = false;
  });
```